# Override Rte.ts Extbase

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

Unfortunately I could not find anything helpful with my google skills. Coming from wordpress I am quite new to TYPO3 and I am a little overwhelmed with it.
I would like to adjust the RTE only in my TYPO3-extension. It should allow iframes and images.
Can anyone help me how to do this in the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images in the textarea would void the clean separation of images and text, but there is an extension [rte_ckeditor_image](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/rte_ckeditor_image/) which would enables it.

Otherwise you could define configuration presets, which you could assign to your fields.

More info in the [manual for the rte_ckeditor](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor/9.5/en-us/Index.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found an other solution without messing with the presets of the ckeditor. I added a field where the user can add all available content elements he/she wants.
https://typo3worx.eu/2016/11/use-content-element-relations-in-typo3-extensions/